# Wait for multiple HTTP calls to end before doing something

Tags: angular

I want to make two HTTP calls.

Below is my TypeScript Code

```
   CheckLogIn() {
    this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'api/LogIn/CheckLogIn/' + this.StaffCode).subscribe(result => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (result == true) {
          this.GetUserName();
          sessionStorage.setItem("UserID", this.StaffCode);
          this.router.navigate(['/log-tracker']);
        }
      }, 5000)
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }

 GetUserName() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Common/GetUserName/' + sessionStorage.getItem("UserID"), { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      sessionStorage.setItem("UserName", result);
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Here Inside CheckLogin() I  am calling an endpoint and within response of this call I am invoking another one (GetUserName) and then redirecting to another page.

But checkLogin Does not wait for GetUserName to finish and redirect to page before second call finishes its work , hence session username is always null .

I tried using SetTimeout Function but it does not work here , is there any other way to put a delay before redirection , or any way to make first call wait until second call finishes its work ?

Comment: I edit your question because you're not using two APIs.

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/log-tracker']);` this has to be within `GetUserName` subscribe method.

Comment: use `switchMap`

Comment: @trichetriche , thanks , but look again , hope you will find both api's

Comment: @SujataChanda , I will try that idea

Comment: @Antoniossss , can you refer any post for switchMap

Comment: @Jack right now I see only one. How you built your back-end isn't the concern of the front-end, and either way, your question is about chaining calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not waiting for `GetUserName` within `CheckLogin` you're just calling it and ignoring the result. You could try returning the observable from `GetUserName` - and there's also a good opportunity here to use other RXJS operators.

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

CheckLogIn() {
  this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'api/LogIn/CheckLogIn/' + this.StaffCode)
    .filter(result => result)
    .do(() => sessionStorage.setItem("UserID", this.StaffCode))
    .mergeMap(() => this.GetUserName())
    .subscribe( // This does not execute until the observable from GetUserName is complete
       result => this.router.navigate(['/log-tracker']),
       error => console.log(error)
    );
}

GetUserName() { // I now return an observable
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Common/GetUserName/' + sessionStorage.getItem("UserID"), { responseType: 'text' })
    .do(result => sessionStorage.setItem("UserName", result));
}
```

Now we do the following:

1. Call `CheckLogin`
2. If result is true, continue
3. Set `UserID` in session storage
4. Call `GetUserName` and [replace our observable with it](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)
5. When the observable returned by `GetUserName` completes we can navigate

There's no need to replace RXJS with promises, it has a lot of power when you're doing asynchronous requests - it especially shines in cases such as this when you have multiple calls to do in a certain order, and conditions that have to be met.

Comment: .mergeMap(this.GetUserName()) this wont work without binding.

Comment: What do you mean? Without calling `.bind` on it? It surely will, we are still in the context of the class at this point, so `this` should be as we expect it to be.

Comment: Wait sorry, you actually did the invocation - i read it as function pass - my bad.

Comment: Now that you mention it however, I believe it should be a function rather than just an invocation of `GetUserName`, but using an arrow function should prevent loss of `this` context,

Comment: @UncleDave it says this.http.get(...).filter is not a function . I have added import { Observable,operators } from 'rxjs/Rx'; in my code

Comment: Updated my answer. RXJS takes a modular approach to operators - so you don't end up bundling every single operator when you only use two or three.

Comment: @UncleDave inseed of adding operators, I would rather `pipe` them.

Comment: @Jack I've created a very rough example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utzj3i you can see that the API calls do occur and the navigation happens. Are you sure you're calling the `CheckLogIn` method? @Antoniossss as I understand it `pipe` exists to allow for easier re-use of code, which isn't very relevant here. I understand the argument that one import is less than three, but I think you'd still end up importing `filter` which makes it hardly worth the effort and in my opinion reduction in readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise

```
CheckLogIn() {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'api/LogIn/CheckLogIn/' + this.StaffCode).subscribe(result => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (result == true) {
            this.GetUserName();
            sessionStorage.setItem("UserID", this.StaffCode);
            this.router.navigate(['/log-tracker']);
          }
        }, 5000)
      }, error => console.log(error));
      resolve();
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Call your Checklogin function Like this

```
this.CheckLogIn().then(()=>{
      this. GetUserName();
    });
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap an observable in a promise. Observables have all the functionality of promises and more.